# Unzipping and renaming files/folders

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

Kind of new to python. But after searching and trying to unzip some folders, then rename them that don't have static names. For example the file is New_05222016. The #s are the date, and that always changes. I want it to be a unzipped folder that is labeled "New".

This is what i have so far. It will unzipp my file, but won't rename it.

```
import zipfile,fnmatch,os

rootPath = r"C:/Users/Bob/Desktop/Bill"
pattern = '*.zip'
New = 'New*'


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))
        zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(root, filename)).extractall(os.path.join(root, os.path.splitext(filename)[0]))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(dir,New):
        os.rename(dir,'C:/Users/Bob/Desktop/Bill/New')
```

if tried other ways. Such as just os.rename and typing it out. But i'm at a loss of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

os.rename() will work fine, just be sure to specify the full path.

I've modified your example using os.listdir() to store the name of the unzipped directory and then renamed it using os.rename(). I also used re to leave the name of the zipped file intact.

```
import zipfile,fnmatch,os, re

rootPath = r"C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Bill"
pattern = '*.zip'
New = 'New*'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))
        zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(root,     filename)).extractall(os.path.join(root, os.path.splitext(filename)[0]))

for dirName in os.listdir(rootPath):
    if not re.search("zip", dirName):
        os.rename(os.path.join(rootPath, dirName), os.path.join(rootPath,"New"))
```

I hope this helps!